# How to copy a file into Micro SD via USB in Android?

Tags: usb, external-sd, file-transfer, file-management

How can I copy a file into micro SD of an Android phone connected via USB to a PC with Windows?

Comment: Related: http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/q/642/87

Comment: This is phone specific.  Please edit question to include phone make and model

Answer (score 7):

```
Settings >> Connect to PC >> USB Connection Type
```

should be set to "Disk drive" (you can set this as a default connection type, but I prefer to do it manually when I need it).

Also, you can set it via the notifcations bar by clicking on the USB connection type as it appears; a selection box of the various options should appear.

Once mounted, you can open on your PC, and drag-n-drop, or what-have-you.

NOTE (from the Incredible manual, p29):

> **Disk drive**
>
> This mode is available only when you
>   have installed a microSD card on your
>   phone. Select  this mode when you want
>   to use your storage card as a USB
>   thumb drive, and copy files  between
>   your phone’s storage card and your
>   computer.
>
> **When Disk Drive mode is
>   enabled while your phone is connected
>   to the computer, you will  not be able
>   to run applications that use the
>   storage card, such as Music or Photos.**
>   For more  information, see “Copying
>   files to and from the storage card” in
>   this chapter.

Comment: Also looks like apps installed to the SD card are also deactivated while mounted/connected.

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention which Android phone you've got, depending on which phone (and how much your manufacturer's customised) you've got, it may be slightly different from OtherMichael's instructions.

With stock Android (as on the Nexus One, HTC Magic, G1, etc), when you plug your phone into the PC's USB you should see a USB icon appear in the notification area. Pull the notification area down and you should see "`USB connected: Select to copy files to/from your computer`." Press this and you get the option to "`Mount`". Pressing this connects your phone's SD to the PC.

Other manufacturers customize things slightly with their custom UIs, for instance if you have a phone with Samsung's TouchWiz UI on it, you get a menu up as soon as you plug into USB, with options to select USB Mode, on the you'd pick Mass Storage, and then do as above. I think HTC's Sense UI also customizes things slightly, but I can't remember exactly how that works.

Comment: Some apps will automatically mount the phone for you when you plug it in. Note that some functionality on the phone is disabled while it is so mounted.