# How do I download the music from my computer to my samsung moment?

Tags: music-player

Can someone please give me a straight answer im leaving for Costa Rica in the morning and need my music.

Comment: In case you didn't know how to just copy the files onto your phone over USB, see the answers on this previous question http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/962/how-to-copy-a-file-into-micro-sd-via-usb-in-android Just create a folder on your SD card (I called mine Music) and copy the MP3s straight over.

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to (semi-)automate the process. I'm assuming you don't want to use an app to manage this. (There are dozens. I expect some other answers will suggest some.)

I also assume that you know how to connect to your PC and turn on "USB Storage".

Just copy your music files to your SD card. The music player will find the tracks wherever you have them, but you should probably put them in a "Music" subfolder so that **you** can find them easily.

It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the music to any location on your phone, and the music player will detect the location automatically.

Al has posted how you can transfer your file with a PC and USB cable, if for some reason it doesn't work for you you can install Awesome Drop from the Market and then use Dashwire's [awesome drop](http://labs.dashwire.com/drop) to transfer the file using internet connection.